# For $2\times 2$ matrices proof that: If row-vectors are linearly dependent, then $\det=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, proof-writing, determinant

> For $2 \times 2$ matrices $A = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12}\\  a_{21} &
> a_{22} \end{pmatrix}$ prove that: If row-vectors of $A$ are linearly
>   dependent, then $\det(A)=0$

I'm not sure how to do this correct. I would start by calculating its determinant:

$\det(A)=a_{11}a_{22} - a_{21}a_{12}$

Now let $\det(A)=0$

Then $0=a_{11}a_{22} - a_{21}a_{12} \Leftrightarrow a_{11}a_{22}=a_{21}a_{12}$

So we have $a_{11}=\frac{a_{21}a_{12}}{a_{22}}; \,\,\,\ a_{12}=\frac{a_{11}a_{22}}{a_{21}};\,\,\,\, a_{21}=\frac{a_{11}a_{22}}{a_{12}};\,\,\,\ a_{22}=\frac{a_{21}a_{12}}{a_{11}}$

If we write this as a matrix, we have
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{a_{21}a_{12}}{a_{22}} & \frac{a_{11}a_{22}}{a_{21}}\\ 
\frac{a_{11}a_{22}}{a_{12}} & \frac{a_{21}a_{12}}{a_{11}}
\end{pmatrix}$$

But now I have a problem, I don't know how to continue :s

On paper I have created following linear system:

$$\text{I}: \lambda_1 \frac{a_{21}a_{12}}{a_{22}} + \lambda_2 \frac{a_{11}a_{22}}{a_{21}} = 0$$

$$\text{II}: \lambda_1 \frac{a_{11}a_{22}}{a_{12}} + \lambda_2 \frac{a_{21}a_{12}}{a_{11}}=0$$

I have tried to form for $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ hoping that both will be equal to zero so that I had linearly dependent row-vectors but no..

Is there maybe a better way of doing this or is my attempt completely wrong? How you do it good?

Comment: You seem to be trying to prove the converse of the title. Start by assuming that the rows are linearly dependent and then show that the determinant is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition of linear dependence the second row is a multiple of the first (or vice versa).  This means that:

$$ {{a}_{11}}{{a}_{22}}-{{a}_{12}}{{a}_{21}}={{a}_{11}}\left( b{{a}_{12}} \right)-{{a}_{12}}\left( b{{a}_{11}} \right)=b\left( {{a}_{11}}{{a}_{12}}-{{a}_{12}}{{a}_{11}} \right)=0 $$

Comment: @Ali:  You've proposed a sensible edit, but generally pointing out such minor changes to the OP for their judgement on how to Edit is preferred.